# Movie where a boy gets bigger because of a spaceship that follows him home

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I was around 3, ~13 years ago, when I watched this movie, so I don't remember much.

First thing I remember is two people (brothers maybe), one of them definitely male, are driving home; the one that is definitely male is smaller and seems to be too young to drive, but it shows them driving down a road to go home while a spaceship with a green light follows them.

They get home and later that night the small boy gets bigger. We see this by it showing his feet suddenly pop out from under his blanket and his head staying in the same place. In the morning he notes how his clothes don't fit for some reason.

Sometime later they end up on an alien spaceship.

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies the movie you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Pretty sure this is *[Skyrunners](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1479534/)* (2009).

> Fourteen-year-old Tyler encounters an alien ship which makes him appear older, inexplicably turns him into a "Skyrunner" with incomprehensible powers. This turns his high school life upside down, and may enable him to help his slightly clueless older brother's love life. After he is abducted by beings who intend to takeover of Earth, he must depend on his inept, lovelorn, and goofy brother to rescue him.

The trailer confirms the part about the younger brother growing in size, with his feet popping out from under his blanket, and his clothes not fitting the next morning.

Comment: @Malos - If anyone correctly identifies the movie you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Thanks.